# pfSense: How to add a second WAN subnet for dummies

Tags: subnet, pfsense

Can anyone point me to info on what to change on a pfSense device for a 2nd subnet on a single interface?

My colo provider has allocated a /29 subnet to me of which I can use 3 IP addresses (for some reason they need to use the others). I've tried setting the three IP's as various forms of VIPs but that doesn't work.
Ive connected a Windows laptop directly to the cable, that works.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do.  Assign 2 colo provided IPs to your WAN interface?  Can't think of a reason why that would be useful

Comment: Basically all I want is some extra public IPs. Due to my colo provider falling out with their sister company they had to give up a bunch of IPs. They allocated a /28 subnet but it's not enough - I need a few more IPs. They have managed to "find" a /29 subnet I can use.

Answer (score 1):

They should really route you the second subnet, assigning it to their routers is dumb and a waste of IP space. That doesn't change things too much either way though. A VIP on WAN will suffice in that circumstance unless they did something really stupid with your new subnet, like putting it on an entirely different router and forcing you to route that through it.

Have your provider route you the second subnet, then add the routed block's IPs as type Other VIPs. I wrote about this in much greater detail in https://pfsense.org/book

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same situation with my colo provider. My first subnet was a /28:
197.1.2.0/28 giving me 14 usable IP's, first is the gateway and last is broadcast IP.
Then my new second subnet is a /26:
129.2.3.0/26 giving me 62 usable IP's.

In PFSense I setup the WAN as normal for the first subnet then for the second i had to had a new gateway through "System > Routing > Add new GW"
129.2.3.1 - Gateway
Then add IP's in your range as proxy ARP (or alias etc) in VIP.
Example 129.2.3.2/32 or 129.2.3.3/32 etc.

Route them via 1:1, NAT etc and remember to route your internal IP's on your Outbound NAT so the internal PC's / servers present the correct IP outbound.

Hope this helps
Stephen